# How to copy/paste image from Word to Google docs?

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, google-docs

It sounds strange, but I am not able to copy any image from .doc or .docx to Google docs.

I have a situation when **I need to copy some into from Word document to google docs document** without uploading the whole word document into google. I can copy everything (text with styles and other stuff) until I pick image with it. Not only image doesn't appears in Google docs but it also breaks all styles in other texts (in copy/paste text of course). Not working with only picture copy/paste either (nothing happens). But, I can copy paste pictures from Google docs to docs (or simply copy paste image in internet) without a problem.

Can somebody please explain to me what kind of potential issue it can be and why its happening, or I simply doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs does not seem to allow users to copy these from a clipboard filled with a "cut" or "copy" that contains images and text from MS Word:

- Styles
- Images

However, if you upload a Word document as a new Google Doc, then styles and images seem to work more or less correctly.  I realize you said you don't want to upload the full word document to Google and I also have that use case sometimes myself.  Here is one way I've found to work around this issue:

1. Create a new Word document that will contain only the portions of the document I want to upload to Google.
2. Copy/paste text and images into this new Word document and save the document.
3. Upload the new document into Google as a new Google Doc.

You will now have a Google Doc with your text, images and styles.

Now, if you like, you can select and copy text and images *from the new Google Doc into other Google Docs*, as you were originally trying to do from your Word doc into Google Docs.

(NOTE: I am able to copy one single image at a time from MS Word directly into a Google Doc.)